# hg locate command empty output

Tags: mercurial, phabricator

I have a problem on a repository. I use phabricator as the front-gui of my repository. Recently I found I am not able to open and view a few directories in one repository in phabricator while other directories are fine. Phabricator reports 'hg locate' command output is empty like this:

```
Command failed with error #1!
COMMAND
hg locate --print0 --rev ''\''d8f8fd40c58bf883ec88bd037f96b962ec16f48e'\''' -I './/OA'

STDOUT
(empty)

STDERR
(empty)
```

I tried the same command in the repository on the server and I did get no output. So I just simply tried the command 'hg locate' without any parameter. That command is supposed to list all the files in the repo but I found the output was still empty!

I then cloned the repo to another directory on the server and tried the same 'hg locate' command and found it was find and I got the file list in the repo.

What is the problem with my original repo? Is there any setting to prevent the 'hg locate' command to output anything?

Comment: Have you tried it without the quotes around the pattern?

Comment: yes, I tried that but no luck. I actually also tried to simply run 'hg locate' without any parameters and the output is still empty.

Comment: Check the permissions. Your repositories folder should belong to the Phabricator user (the one you use for daemons and PHP when called by the webserver). Mercurial is rather picky about who owns a repo.

Comment: I checked the permission and the owner of the repo and they are fine. The repo was created by phabricator and it should not have any permission problem. There was no problem to clone it through phabricator. Some folders in the repo can be opened in phabricator but some can not.